# How to get function output with Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, mathematical-optimization

I have a program, which makes Gauss-Jordan transformations (not too pretty, I suppose). I want to get output with Manipulator like that:
[Two-Phase Simplex Method](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TwoPhaseSimplexMethod/)
with only "step number" slider. One table for each step. Is it possible?

Matrix:

```
A = {{6, 15, 6, 1, 0, 0, 9}, {14, 42, 16, 0, 1, 0, 21}, {2, 8, 2, 0, 
0, 1, 4}, {10, -7, -5, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
```

Code:

```
Clear[GaussJordanStep]
GaussJordanStep[M_] := Module[{i, j, m, n, a, b, B = M},
  {m, n} = Dimensions@M;
  {a, b} = 
   Flatten@Thread[{First@
       Ordering[
        Replace[Thread[{Flatten@
            M[[;; -2, Flatten@Position[Last@M, Min[Last@M]]]] ,
           M[[;; -2, -1]]}], {{x1_?Positive, x2_} :> x2/x1, 
          else_ :> \[Infinity]}, {1}]], 
      Position[Last@M, Min[Last@M]]}];
  For[i = 1, i <= m, i++,
   For[j = 1, j <= n, j++,
    If[i == a, B[[i, j]] = M[[i, j]]/M[[a, b]], 
     B[[i, j]] = M[[i, j]] - (M[[i, b]] M[[a, j]])/M[[a, b]]]]];
  B]

Clear[SimplexMethod]
SimplexMethod[M_] := Module[{B = M},
  Print[Grid[B, Dividers -> {-2 -> True, -2 -> True}]];
  Do[B = GaussJordanStep[B]; Print[Grid[B, Dividers -> {-2 -> True, -2 -> True}]]; 
   If[Length@Position[B[[-1]], _?Negative] > 0, Continue[], 
    Break[]], {100}]]
```

Program output:

```
SimplexMethod[A]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First get `SimplexMethod` to return a list, instead of printing them.  Using [`NestWhileList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhileList.html) is a good way to structure the computation of your iterative algorithm.

Mapping the formatting, `Grid[#, Dividers -> {-2 -> True, -2 -> True}] & /@ ...`, on to the list of tables might better occur outside the function `SimplexMethod`.  I usually format at the output point.  Then the tables would remain in a form that is easier to compute with.

```
Clear[SimplexMethod]
SimplexMethod[M_] :=
 Grid[#, Dividers -> {-2 -> True, -2 -> True}] & /@
  NestWhileList[
   GaussJordanStep,
   M,
   Length@Position[#[[-1]], _?Negative] > 0 &,
   1,
   100]
```

Then displaying them in `Manipulate` is relatively straightforward.

```
With[{tables = SimplexMethod[A]},
 Manipulate[
  Pane[tables[[n]], {180, 100}],
  {n, 1, Length@tables, 1}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternative:  Remove the `Grid[#, Dividers -> {-2 -> True, -2 -> True}] & /@` line from `SimplexMethod` and put `Grid` in `Manipulate`.

```
Manipulate[
 Grid[SimplexMethod[A][[n]], Dividers -> {-2 -> True, -2 -> True}],
 {n, 1, Length@SimplexMethod[A], 1}]
```

This recomputes `SimplexMethod[A]` every time the slider is moved.  That would only be a problem if it takes a long time to recompute it.  Otherwise, it's ok.  Also, you can see how `Pane` above makes a fixed-size window for your tables.